# iOS - GMSPlacesClient findAutocompletePredictions support multiple language

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, gmaplacesclient

My iOS app has multilingual support and im using GMSPlacesClient-findAutocompletePredictions to search for city , but haven't found any way to set the language for it.
It is using the device's language, when i set AppleLanguages, i have to restart the application for the new language to be applied.
I need the results to be displayed in the language the user chooses and also need the place names in Englist to sent to the API.
Any ideas please help.
Thank so much.

Comment: There's an ongoing Feature Request in the Google Issue Tracker, and you might want to add your use case and star the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145042910